# Pocketsphinx over zigbee

Tags: arduino, pocketsphinx, zigbee

How can I send the output of the following command line " pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes -lm 8521.lm -dict 8521.dic" to XCTU console in order to control some devices attached to arduino board.

Answer (score 0):

This question for sure is very specific to some hardware/software device which might help to know what it is... also you can ask in the website/forum of the vendor of said device...